# Retrieve Fields/Column Names of a Sharepoint List using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function retrieveFieldsOfListView(){

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = clientContext.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('pranav_list');
var view = list.get_views().getByTitle('Main');
this.listFields = view.get_viewFields();
clientContext.load(this.listFields);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, 
    this.onListFieldsQuerySucceeded9), Function.createDelegate(this, 
    this.onListFieldsQueryFailed));
}
function onListFieldsQuerySucceeded9() {
var fieldsinfo='';
    var fieldEnumerator = listFields.getEnumerator();
    while (fieldEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oField = fieldEnumerator.get_current();
        var fType = oField.get_fieldTypeKind();
        fieldsinfo +='\n '+oField.get_title();
    }
    alert(fieldsinfo);
    }
</script>
```

I want to show the fields of the view using javascript.

Note: My list name is "pranav_list" and view is "Main".

Help..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SP.View.viewFields property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246929(v=office.15).aspx) returns **field names** but not a `Field` client object collection.

The following example demonstrates how to print field names from a View:

```
function retrieveFieldsOfListView(listTitle,viewName){

   var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web();
   var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
   var view = list.get_views().getByTitle(viewName);
   var viewFields = view.get_viewFields();
   context.load(viewFields);
   context.executeQueryAsync(printFieldNames,onError);


   function printFieldNames() {
      var e = viewFields.getEnumerator();
      while (e.moveNext()) {
         var fieldName = e.get_current();
         console.log(fieldName);
      }
   }

   function onError(sender,args)
   {
      console.log(args.get_message());
   }

}
```

Comment: How to get all Items of that View?

Comment: Ok..done.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764636/retrieve-items-from-a-list-view-of-a-sharepoint-list-using-javascript